# When I place a slider inside column I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't represent a size of 2147483592 in Constraints

Tags: android, kotlin, slider, android-jetpack-compose, composable

When I try to use flexible width modifiers either on a parent composable where a slider is placed or on the slider itself I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't represent a size of 2147483592 in Constraints`. Obviously it's a bug in Jetpack Compose.

The bug basically made me abandon my side project because how am I even supposed to use a slider.

To reproduce it use the following code. The exception is thrown even in the preview.

```
Column(Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
   Slider(value = 1f, onValueChange = { })
}
```

The exception disappears when I specify fixed width instead of `IntrinsicSize` value.
It also disappears when I use another overload of the slider where you specify a lambda to the required thumb parameter but this time a thumb on the slider isn't displayed.

Edit: fixed, turned out I needed to update libs though the project wasn't old.